# Regex that contains letters followed by space and numbers

Tags: regex

Would need Regex that contains letters followed by space and then only numbers. Below are few of the patterns:

NDYX 850133

CITX 3430

IG 456781

The string should get end after the numbers.

Comment: What have you attempted until now?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
/[A-Z]+\s+\d+/
```

or case insensitive, in case small letters possible:

```
/[A-Z]+\s+\d+/i
```

Comment: Thanks for the update. ^[A-Z]+\s+\d+/ or ^[A-Z]+\s+\d+/i are accepting letters followed by spaces and digits but also allowing all types of characters after the digits. I do not want to add any other thing after digits.

Comment: if "AAA 111" is all you want, then add start ^ and end $ to the regex:  /^[A-Z]+\s+\d+$/

Comment: /^[A-Z]+\s\d+$/ in case there should be only a single space, between letters and numbers

Comment: Thanks! This approach worked well as pre the requirement!